# How to compare these bioinformatical categorical data

Tags: categorical-data, biostatistics, bioinformatics

I have the information for 100  positions in the genome of 10 cases and 10 controls.

The response for every individual and each SNP (Single-nucleotide polymorphism) position is 0, 1 or 2 (these represent the number of ancestry genes).

How to compare this categorical data?

```
        pos1    pos2    ...    pos100        ancestry
ind_1    1        2               0             0.01
ind_2    1        1               1             0.02
.        .        .               .               .
.        .        .               .               .
.        .        .               .               .
ind_n    1        0               2             0.03
```

Comment: It depends on the exact nature of your research question and the assumptions you are willing to make about the alleles and their inheritance, but a pretty common approach for this type of comparison in statistical genetics is some sort of variant of the Chi-squared test. That is, you would essentially collapse the information into a 2x3 table of counts, indicating how many individuals in each of the intervention groups has 0, 1, or 2 copies of the allele in question. You may then apply some sort of weighting based on assumed inheritance patterns (additive, dominant, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are both statistical and biological issues in your problem.

If we could ignore the fact that your `pos` values are genomic loci, then the problem could be set up as a set of Chi-squared tests, as suggested by @Ryan Simmons in a comment. The Chi-squared test for each locus would determine whether the distributions of (0,1,2) "ancestry" allele counts differ between your two groups. If all you care about is the total number of "ancestry" alleles at each locus, you could just compare the average number of ancestry alleles per individual between the two groups in *t*-tests or in a linear model or ANOVA that includes loci as a factor. You have no pre-specified hypothesis about the loci that will differ, however, so you would have to correct any *p*-values for the [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem) you are making: if you accept *p* < 0.05 as a significance criterion, then even if there are no true differences you would detect erroneous "significant" differences at about 375 loci. Follow the [`multiple-comparisons`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multiple-comparisons/info) tag on this site for extensive discussion.

The origin of your data as genomic loci, however, adds additional considerations. You probably do not have 7500 independent loci, as linkage disequilibrium (co-inheritance of loci that are close on the genome) means that the "ancestry" allele counts are likely to co-vary among sites. If you ignore this issue you will get into trouble when you try to publish your results. This might actually help you identify genomic locations that differ among your 2 groups, as you should be able to use information about actual genomic locations to pool results among closely linked loci.

This is an issue addressed by the [Bioconductor project](https://www.bioconductor.org/), which provides methods for large-scale analysis of genomic and similar data. Genetic analysis is not my expertise, but I did quickly find a [`snpStats`](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/snpStats.html) package that might work for your application, or at least serve as an introduction to other related packages that might better meet your needs. In the long run you will be better off learning about methods that have been honed through experience to deal with the types of data that you have, rather than just trying to start from scratch yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the data you are describing so please correct me if my assumption are not correct.

First you should have a metric for the relation between a feature (SNP position) and the concept (ancestry).
While there are plenty of metrics for such relationships (e.g., mutual information, covariance, correlation) in your case it seems that the domain might dictate the relation of interest.
For example, there might be biological reason to  condition on the cases where the SNP=2 or to  turn the ancestry in to a binary feature based on a threshold of biological meaning.

Now we can move to finding regions of interest.
If the region is continuous you can just scan the SNPs from 0 to 7500.
Once you encounter an SNP whose relation with the concept is good enough, start a region.
While its neighbour also has a good enough relation, extend the region.
Otherwise, close that region (and start a new one on the next good enough SNP).

I assume here that a region of interest is one whose all SNPs are of interest.
In case the region of interest is defined differently, please explain in a comment the definitions.

In case the SNPs doesn't have to be continuous, we have a feature selection problem - choosing a subset of the features.
There are many algorithms for that, most of them work with common statistical measures of feature-concept relations. If you use a domain specific measure, they feature selection algorithm should get a measure to estimate a set of features for the domain.

Note that your number of features is high and your number of cases is low (and even way lower than the number of features). In such scenario, it is very likely that noise and randomness will lead unrelated features to look related and vice verse.
You can cope with that by requiring a high threshold for the relation.
The fact the you are interested in region will also reduce the noise (the probability of getting a random region as correlated decreases dramatically with its length).